# How can I create a game object and make it immediately draggable by mouse?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I've been working in a pet simulation game in Unity. The idea of the interaction I'm trying to build is the following:

- I have a UI Canvas with a Panel that will contain Sprites for Every Action available.
- The expected behaviour would be so that if I drag an item (sprite) from the UI Panel to the "3D world" it would instantiate a 3D version of that item in the current mouse position and it would immediately be draggable by mouse.

First of all, I don't know if this is possible neither do I have any idea of how to do it.

I have already tried to instantiate that game object and give it a script to allow dragging and dropping. Already gave it the mouse position when instantiated, but it will not be attached to the mouse since I did not click it in the first place.

I know how to do things in a separate way but not together and I don't even know if it is possible.

Does anyone have a suggestion or has done this before?

Comment: Read tutorials first. Too broad.

Comment: @user202729 I've done it. I haven't read everything but I've spent the last 6 months around Unity. I just need an idea on how to build this interaction. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @HenriqueFerreira, Can you show us what you have tried to make it drag with the mouse?  Also will this object be draggable after you release the mouse button for the first time? (So I put a puppy in my shop, Can I click him and move him later?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving an exact solution is difficult without knowing your exact scene setup, and knowing if you use Unity's event system, the Touch class, or any external library.

However, here are a few general ideas that should help you:

- You don't necessary have to detect the touch from the 3d object. Since you instanciate the 3d object according to which 2d sprite is selected, it means that the 2d sprite "knows" the 3d object. So after creating, the 2d sprite could have its image disabled, but still detect the drag info and call a function on the 3d object to update its position
- To go further, you can even instantiate all the 3d objects from the beggining, but disable the mesh renderer component so they are invisible. The 2d sprite just makes it visible when at the right position
- If you still want the 3d object to detect touches by itself, look into the IDragHandler interface of unity. Have a script implementing it and you will recieve drag events on your object without having to detect a click first

Comment: Thank you very much, I made it with the IDragHandler interface implementation. Very thankful, it worked fine.